# Favorite/Remove/Ignore action text in Tag Tooltip in SO is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tooltips

I've just noticed that in SO (but not other SE sites -- I've tested Math and Programmers) the text for the Favorite/Remove/Ignore action in the Tag Tooltip doesn't match the action.

I'm talking about what you see when you hover over the symbol in the top left corner of the tooltip.

What I see is:

```
Tag state | Symbol      | Text when hovering                 | Actual Action

Neither   | Yellow Star | add this tag to your favorites     | Ignore
Ignored   | X           | remove this tag from all favorites | Favorite
Favorite  | Red Star    | add this tag to your ignored       | Remove
```

Comment: It looks like SO is waiting on a code deploy the other sites have already gotten, so it's possible this'll be fixed with that update. Definitely off right now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are changing it to

> toggle this tag between favorite, ignored, and normal

for all 3 states.

(aka *trilean!*)